# Tags picker control

Tags: javascript, tags, controls, picker

Is there any good (free or paid) JavaScript controls, which is like StackOverflow tags picker? (You can see it while asking new question under the title "Tags").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple) configured for multiple values is a pretty good start. I would think with a little bit of re-restyling that it could be a lot more like the SO tag browser; also it's free.

Comment: [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) is probably the better option now. My answer was written over 3 years ago!

Answer (score 4):

[Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) is a good example, they have a nice multi-select option.

[image]

Comment: How do you use Chosen? There are no instructions on their page... thanks.